# Rails I18n via database column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have a legacy database table that has columns name_en and name_es and was wondering what the best way to query in ActiveRecord for either translation based on the user's i18n preference would be.

The i18n implementations I see for Rails tend to be more about storing translations in a separate hash or table, but I don't want to change the structure of the database.

Currently in the old PHP app, I send an argument to the mysql query to replace the name_**lang** and return `name_en` or `name_es AS name` for displaying when I call the row's id.

Comment: Using a [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html) would seem a good approach.

Comment: @Zabba: scopes would be a bit long to implement there

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should create an initializer in which you'd put:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.has_translation(*attributes)    
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      define_method "#{attribute}" do
        self.send "#{attribute}_#{I18n.locale}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your models:

```
has_translation :name, :whatever
```

So that it will automatically call the proper column name depending on your current locale. In your view:

```
@variable.name # calling @variable.name_en if locale = :en
               #         @variable.name_es if locale = :es
```

Of course, I assumed there was no already existing table named `name`.