# multiple languages models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, internationalization

I've been asked to design a multiple language application and I need advice with which is the best approach with Rails.

Basically all the tables have some common fields that doesn't need to 
be translated and some others that need translation.

thank you

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700054/rails-i18n-via-database-column

Answer (score 5):

For this purpose, will approach gem [globalize3](https://github.com/globalize/globalize). Easy to use.

In your gemfile:

```
gem 'globalize'
```

Model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :title, :text
end
```

And migration:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
    Article.create_translation_table! :title => :string, :text => :text
  end

  def down
    drop_table :articles
    Article.drop_translation_table!
  end
end
```

And run

```
rake db:migrate
```