# How to handle i18n for model data on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

On this question [Rails I18n via database column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700054/rails-i18n-via-database-column) the user has a legacy app and have two columns for english and other language for a specific attribute. If you are doing an app from scratch, how the best way to handle those situations?
Example: A blog when the user will post in english and portuguese , how do you handle those posts?

Thanks!