# Translating entries in the database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

In our application **users** can create a set of categories. Those categories each contain products. On the website **customers** can then see the categories - currently only in one language.

We would like to add translations so that the customers can view the data in different languages. This would mean that the the user has to be able to add translations to the actual data.

Based on this question: [Rails I18n via database column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700054/rails-i18n-via-database-column) I should add a couple of database columns for each locale.

Has anyone solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) numerous times and always liked it. Maybe it can help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar kind of requirement where this [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends) helped me .  I was not changing the language but i wanted to externalize some of the currency parameters as the currency per country changes.  Here is my sample application [code](https://github.com/ankit8898/translation-with-redis)